# Components not on expected row when using colspan

Tags: css, primefaces, xhtml, panelgrid

I have a panelgrid with 5 rows and 7 columns within and have tried to use colspan to line up the different components within the columns. I'll stick my xhtml below:

```
            <p:panelGrid>
                <p:row>
                    <p:column>

                        <p:row>
                            <p:column>
                                <p:outputLabel value="Job Status:" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column colspan="4">
                                <p:selectOneMenu value="#{myBean.jobStatus}">
                                   f:selectItems here
                                </p:selectOneMenu>
                            </p:column>                                                     
                            <p:column>
                                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="cbRepetition"
                                    value="#{myBean.isRepeatable}"
                                </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column>
                                <p:outputLabel value="Terminate repetition of this job?" />
                            </p:column>
                        </p:row>

                        <p:row>
                            <p:column>
                                <p:outputLabel value="Positions:" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column>
                                <p:spinner id="position1"
                                    value="#{myBean.selectedPosition1}" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column>
                                <p:spinner id="position2"
                                    value="#{myBean.selectedPosition2}" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column>
                                <p:spinner id="position3"
                                    value="#{myBean.selectedPosition3}" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column>
                                <p:spinner id="position4"
                                    value="#{myBean.selectedPosition4}" />
                            </p:column>                                                     
                            <p:column>
                                <p:outputLabel value="Occurrences:" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column>
                                <p:spinner id="occurrences"
                                    value="#{myBean.selectedOccurrences}" />
                            </p:column>
                        </p:row>

                        <p:row>
                            <p:column>
                                <p:outputLabel value="Date/Time:" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column colspan="4">
                                <p:calendar id="dateTime" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"
                                    value="#{myBean.selectedDateTime}">
                                </p:calendar>
                            </p:column>                                                     
                            <p:column>
                                <p:outputLabel value="Job Location:" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column>
                                <p:selectOneMenu id="locationDd"
                                    value="#{myBean.selectedLocationId}">
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select" itemValue="0" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Australia" itemValue="1" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Springfield" itemValue="2" />
                                </p:selectOneMenu>
                            </p:column>
                        </p:row>

                        <p:row>
                            <p:column>
                                <p:outputLabel value="Comments:" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column colspan="6">
                                <p:inputTextarea />
                            </p:column>
                        </p:row>

                    </p:column>
                </p:row>
            </p:panelGrid>
```

I've refactored the code a little bit, for example the jobStatus selectOneMenu is actually a custom component I've created, but I'm confident this isn't the issue as it's been used elsewhere in my project without any trouble.

This panelGrid is sat within a panel within a form.

I'm hoping it is obvious what I am trying to achieve, but what I'm actually getting is as below:

[image]

I've used CSS to make the spinners smaller as they should be just big enough to fit an integer 0-9, but this has had no effect, any suggestions why things aren't dislpaying on the correct rows or things I can do to make them display as I wish?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've realized I just needed to remove the initial `<p:row>` and `<p:column>` and it works fine.

Comment: the initial 'and'? Do you mean the initial 'row'?